# Ubuntu 14.04 - upgrade Apache2 to 2.4.10

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, apache2.4

I am experiencing this bug:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56480

It doesn't seem like the version containing the fix (2.4.10) is available to me:

```
# apt-cache policy apache2
  apache2:
    Installed: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4
    Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9
```

What's the best way to fix the apache2 bug?

Answer (score 0):

Install the candidate version and see if the fix has been backported into it. If not, open a bug against the package in Ubuntus bugtracker.